# Defining namespace in GQL query

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gql

I do have a quite simple question. I'd like to define the namespace when doing a GQL query.

For example

```
inventory_query = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM StockItemModel WHERE version = KEY('" +version.key.urlsafe()+ "') AND on_stock = TRUE", namespace=namespace)
```

The documentation states nothing about a namespace and I cannot use ndb.query since there is a circular dependency.

Is there a way to define the namespace at a GQL query ?

Answer (score 1):

*As I found a answer to this question myself I'd like to share it.*

I've not found any possibility to define a namespace in GQL query. However the query above can be rewritten as the following.

```
inventory_query = ndb.Query(kind = 'StockItemModel', namespace = stock_namespace)
inventory_query = stock_query.filter(ndb.GenericProperty('version') == version.key)
```

Hope this helps some people ;)